# When to stop in a proof by contradiction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While proving that

> If $A$ is a set, then $A$ does not have any bijection with its power set $\wp(A)$

we assume there is such a bijection $f$. Then we define subset $B=\{a\in A:a\notin f(a)\}\;.$ Then we try to derive a contradiction by asserting that if for some $a_0\in A$, we have $f(a_0)=B$, then $a_0\in B\implies a_0\in A-B$, conradiction; and $a_0\in A-B\implies a_0\in B$, contradiction.

My question is: why don't we stop at $a_0\in B\implies a_0\in A-B$? Isn't that itself contradiction?

Comment: You might stop there. In fact, you can make a more *direct* proof that any $f\colon A\to\wp(A)$ fails to be surjective by showing that $f(a)\ne B$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: Where did you find the proof you quote?

Comment: We can't stop where you've mentioned, since if only this implication were true (and not the latter one), then it doesn't cover the case that $a_{0}\not\in B.$ It could still be the case that $a_{0}\not\in B,$ and the map is actually well defined.

Comment: I am confused!!! @HagenvonEitzen, you say I can stop there, but other comment and the answer says that I can't !!!

Comment: At the first contradiction, you've only shown that $a_0$ can't be in $B$, so we reject $a_0\in B$. Only when you've shown that it can't be in the complement of $B$ either do we have to back up further, and reject the existence of a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the proof assumes that $a_0\in B$ in order to get the contradictory consequence that $a_0\in A-B$. So this contradiction only proves that your secondary assumption $a_0\in B$ was wrong.

That allows us to deduce $a_0\not\in B$ (since assuming the opposite gave a contradiction). But this also gives a contradiction, so now we know our primary assumption ($f$ exists)  was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  But after finding $a_0\in B$, is wrong, I become relieved. How shall I suspect in such proofs that another contradiction is coming?

Comment: I mean, in other proofs which use contradiction, we almost always stop as soon as contradiction is derived. What makes us sure that proof should not go further?

Comment: Basically the pattern of proof by contradiction is that you make an assumption, then derive a contradiction, and this shows that your assumption is wrong. When you make another assumption, that's like starting a new proof by contradiction inside the first proof, so you need another contradiction. But if there's only one assumption, you only need one contradiction to disprove it.

Comment: It's sort of like doing a sudoku: say you get to a position where you can't see how to go any further, so you try putting a 3 in square A. That gets you a bit further, but eventually you can't deduce anything else, so you try putting an 8 in square B. Then you deduce some more, but reach a point where it can't work. That's a contradiction, but the 3 in A could still be right - all you know is that if it is, the 8 in B was wrong. And perhaps now when you try the other option for B it goes wrong again - if so this means your 3 in A was wrong too.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.